# Parse login with new user shows previous user info

Tags: swift, parse-platform, logout, pfquery, pfuser

I'm using Parse.com in my app written in Swift. I have a tab bar and make queries on almost every view controller. When I log out with a user and then log in with a different user some of the previous user's related info stays on the other view controllers until I completely shut down and reboot the app.

Any idea why this is? I have my query functions in viewDidLoad() and I'm not sure if this makes a difference or not. I wanted to keep them in viewDidLoad() and not viewWillAppear() because I want to cut down on the amount of queries and don't want the user to constantly make queries when switching from tab to tab in the app when they haven't made any changes on those views.

-I also tried calling PFQuery.clearAllCachedResults() in my logout action but this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you might want to have a notification posted when user logs out, so that all other controllers, can do a cleanup or do whatever is necessary

Comment: When you logout and log back in, are you reloading your current view controller?

Comment: @Shripada how would I post a notification to clear everything when the user logs out? That's what I was trying to do with PFQuery.clearAllCachedResults().

Comment: @mn1 I'm reloading the data but only if I have my queries in viewWillAppear. Which causes the app to make a query each time the user switch tabs or goes to a different screen.